# Error dding file to usb on Chromebook

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, live-usb, chrome-book

I have a Snow Bara samsung chromebook, I want to use USB boot to boot kali linux, without messing up my computer. I used `enable_usb_dev_boot` to get it to boot from usb, but it has problems when flashing the usb. I created a backup USB, and got a 32 gigabyte usb stick. The kali linux website says for their image, you need at least an 8 gb usb stick. The command that they use is

```
xzcat kali-$ver-exynos.img.xz | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```

I changed the xzcat name, and path to the corresponding one in my chromebook. I then changed the path of the dd command, to  `media/removable/USB\ Drive` because that was the path of my usb (I checked this). Whenever I use dd it says error this is a directory. I then changed the path to `/media/removable/USB\` Drive/ and it said permission denied. I don't see my error. current command is : `sudo xzcat home/chronos/user/Downloads/kali-chromebook.img.xz | dd of=/media/removable/USB\ Drive bs=512k` 
[image: command]

Comment: whenever i go to the usb after running these commands i get :  `localhost removable # cd USB\ Drive/
Prompt:localhost USB Drive # ls
USB Drive bs=512k
Prompt:localhost USB Drive # `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is correct, `/media/removable/USB\ Drive/` is a directory but you should be writing with `dd` to the block device, so you need to find the corresponding block device. The output of `mount` or `lsblk` can help you with that.

If you have so much problems understanding the difference between block devices and mount points and also interpreting error messages then [Kali Linux is not for you](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) at the moment.

It's usually recommended to use `bs=4M` for flash drives instead of `bs=512k`. But hey, you use Kali Linux, you know what you are doing.

Comment: I have used unix, and kali but i have never created a bootable or live usb. I was able to use ` xzcat /home/chronos/user/Downloads/kali-2017.2-exynos.img.xz | dd of=/media/removable/USB\ Drive\ bs=512k`  and then us mv to move it to my usb drive. Only to find that even with cross system, and usb boot, samsung has no bios.